# Will 2-methylbutanal undergo aldol condensation

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, aldol-reaction

Will 2-methylbutanal undergo aldol condensation?

We are taught that it will not because the +I effect makes the carbanion unstable, but if we make an enolate ion, isn't it resonance stabilized by the C=O group?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no reason why the aldehyde cannot undergo an aldol reaction with itself. Enolates are not rendered unstable by the presence of additional alkyl substituents; in fact they are considered to be *more* stable. (See: formation of silyl enol ethers with $\ce{Et3N}$/$\ce{Me3SiCl}$.)

However, there is no way it can eliminate $\ce{H2O}$ to form the α,β-unsaturated ketone, since the aldol product does not have any α-hydrogens. Strictly you cannot call it an aldol *condensation*, although often no distinction is made in the literature between an aldol addition and a condensation.

[image: Aldol product]

The formation of the β-hydroxyketone above was reported as long ago as 1924, the reagent being potassium carbonate. More recently, in an attempt to make a 1,3-dioxolane from 2-methylbutanal with potassium t-butoxide and 2-chloroethanol, it was found that the enolisable aldehyde underwent "self-condensation" instead: [*Org. Lett.*, **2006**, *8*, 3745](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ol0613113).